# Issue passing Node arguments to PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to start a process using PM2, but it doesn't seem to pick up node arguments relative to the current working directory.

Running this from `/path/to/dir/` works:

```
pm2 start dist/main.js --node-args="-r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js" -- -c config.json
```

whereas using this ecosystem file:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "server",
            "script": "dist/main.js",
            "instances": 2,
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "cwd": "/path/to/dir/",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "config.json"
            ],
            "node_args": [
                "-r",
                "./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js"
            ],
            "watch": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and running:
`pm2 start server`

gives me the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module './tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js'`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hi, were you later able to fix this? I am currently facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"node_args": ["-r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js"]
```

[Check this](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

And make sure your file is in same directory else you need to give full p ath to file.